# A good Java SWT example using multiple CComboboxes

Tags: java, user-interface, swt

I created a simple Java application thats able to scramble datafiles. It works fine with my tester class, but in order to give this tool to some document developers, it has to have a gui.
So...
I'm using Eclipse Kepler with WindowBuilder. As a newbie i'm really struggling with this gui. I've made several attempts to create the gui like the enclosed picture, but i'm not able to 'get' all the selected information. I tried inner classes etc. but don't know how to do this.
So i really hope someone can help.

--- after several comments that stated that my question isn't clear i changed the question. I hope this will make clear want i want to achieve. ---

I created the following class:

```
package com.scrambledata.gui;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.FileDialog;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Group;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.FormToolkit;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ToolBar;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.CCombo;

public class gui {
private Text txtFile2Read, txtScrambleFile;
protected Shell shlScrambledata;

public String docType, docModel, fakeAddresslist, file2scramble;


/**
 * Launch the application.
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        gui window = new gui();
        window.open();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Open the window.
 */
public void open() {
    Display display = Display.getDefault();
    createContents();
    shlScrambledata.open();
    shlScrambledata.layout();
    while (!shlScrambledata.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        } // end if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
        //display.dispose();
    } // end while (!shlScrambledata.isDisposed()) {
} // end public void open() {

/**
 * Create contents of the window.
 */
private void createContents() {
    shlScrambledata = new Shell();
    shlScrambledata.setSize(450, 405);
    shlScrambledata.setText("ScrambleData");


    // Create the document type group
    Group docTypeGroup = new Group(shlScrambledata, SWT.SHADOW_ETCHED_IN);
    docTypeGroup.setLocation(10, 10);
    docTypeGroup.setSize(225, 49);
    docTypeGroup.setText("Choose a Document Type");

    final CCombo cmbDocType = new CCombo(docTypeGroup, SWT.BORDER);
    cmbDocType.setItems(new String[] {"ACC710", "COMKB", "DEB442", "DEB443", "DEB444", "DEB814", "FAC617", "INC411", "INC715", "KLT334 ", "KLT355", "KLT358", "KLT361", "OVK710", "PKOA"});
    cmbDocType.setBounds(10, 18, 198, 21);
    cmbDocType.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
          System.out.println(cmbDocType.getText());

        }

        public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
          System.out.println(cmbDocType.getText());
        }
      });


    // create the documentmodel group
    Group docModelGroup = new Group(shlScrambledata, SWT.SHADOW_ETCHED_IN);
    docModelGroup.setLocation(10, 71);
    docModelGroup.setSize(225, 49);
    docModelGroup.setText("Choose a document model.");

    final CCombo cmbDocModel = new CCombo(docModelGroup, SWT.BORDER);
    cmbDocModel.setItems(new String[] {"XML", "FlatFile", "COMklantbeeld"});
    cmbDocModel.setBounds(10, 18, 198, 21);
    cmbDocModel.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
          System.out.println(cmbDocModel.getText());
        }

        public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
          System.out.println(cmbDocModel.getText());
        }
      });

    // create the file chooser for the fake addresslist
    Group grpSelectTheFake = new Group(shlScrambledata, SWT.SHADOW_ETCHED_IN);
    grpSelectTheFake.setText("Select the fake address list.");
    grpSelectTheFake.setBounds(10, 131, 333, 66);

    txtFile2Read = new Text(grpSelectTheFake, SWT.BORDER);
    txtFile2Read.setBounds(10, 26, 211, 21);

    Button btnFileChooser = new Button(grpSelectTheFake, SWT.PUSH);
    btnFileChooser.setBounds(240, 24, 75, 25);
    btnFileChooser.setText("Browse");       
    btnFileChooser.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
          public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
          FileDialog dialog = new FileDialog(shlScrambledata, SWT.NULL);
          String path = dialog.open();
          if (path != null) {

          File file = new File(path);
          if (file.isFile())
              displayFakeAddressListFiles(new String[] { file.toString()});
          else
              displayFakeAddressListFiles(file.list());

          }
          }
      });  

    // create the filechooser for the file to be scrambled
    Group grpSelectScrambleFile = new Group(shlScrambledata, SWT.SHADOW_ETCHED_IN);
    grpSelectScrambleFile.setText("Select the file that you want to scramble.");
    grpSelectScrambleFile.setBounds(10, 213, 333, 66);

    txtScrambleFile = new Text(grpSelectScrambleFile, SWT.BORDER);
    txtScrambleFile.setBounds(10, 26, 211, 21);

    Button btnSelectScrambleFile = new Button(grpSelectScrambleFile, SWT.NONE);
    btnSelectScrambleFile.setBounds(240, 24, 75, 25);
    btnSelectScrambleFile.setText("Browse");


    btnSelectScrambleFile.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
          public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
          FileDialog dialog = new FileDialog(shlScrambledata, SWT.NULL);
          String path = dialog.open();
          if (path != null) {

          File file = new File(path);
          if (file.isFile())
              displayScrambleFiles(new String[] { file.toString()});
          else
              displayScrambleFiles(file.list());

          }
          }
      });  

    Button btnScramble = new Button(shlScrambledata, SWT.NONE);
    btnScramble.setBounds(23, 309, 75, 25);
    btnScramble.setText("Scramble!");
    btnScramble.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter(){
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
              System.out.println("DocType: "  );
              System.out.println("DocModel: "  );
              System.out.println("AddressFile: "  );
              System.out.println("File2Scramble: "  );

        }
    });

} // end createContents




 public void displayFakeAddressListFiles(String[] files) {
      for (int i = 0; files != null && i < files.length; i++) {
          txtFile2Read.setText(files[i]);
          txtFile2Read.setEditable(true);
          System.out.println(txtFile2Read.getText());
      }
} // end method public void displayFakeAddressListFiles(String[] files) {

 public void displayScrambleFiles(String[] files) {
      for (int i = 0; files != null && i < files.length; i++) {
          txtScrambleFile.setText(files[i]);
          txtScrambleFile.setEditable(true);
          System.out.println(txtFile2Read.getText());
      }
} // end method public void displayScrambleFiles(String[] files) {
} // end public class gui {
```

This will create the following screen:
[image]

When i select a value in the combo boxes i see the selected value in my Eclipse console. If i select the fake address i see the selected value in my gui. I also get the selected value in my console.
When i select the file i want to scramble i do see the correct file in my gui, however my console is showing the information from the previous filechooser (fake address).

Question 1: how can i get the correct information in my console (so fakeaddresslist chooser AND file2scramble chooser). I expect that i have to use an inner class for this, but can't get it working.

If i press the Scramble! button i would like to start the actual scramble class. This class requires the document type, model, file2scramble and the fakeaddresslist. So i need to know the information selected by the user in the fields above. For this test i want to print the selected / given information in the console, just to prove i have it.

Qeustion 2: How do i get and 'store' the information from the comboboxes and filechoosers?

I hope that my questions are clear now and that someone is able to get me further.

Kind Regards,
Mijno

Comment: Can you boil it down to one (or a a set of) questions?

Comment: Like @Baz said it's not very clear what you're asking?

Comment: Simply said: Can anyone give an example of two CCombo boxes, using SWT that can both receive the selected information (probably by calling an  other inner class).

Comment: @Mijno Receive what selected information? And there's only one combo in your image. Please explain *step-by-step* what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, all you need to do is get the text from the `Widget`s by calling `getText()`. It's not *necessary* (but still possible if you want to) to store them in a `String` as well.

I took the liberty to de-clutter your code a little. It now uses `Layout`s and not absolute positioning, which makes it more robust. If you don't know about layouts, read [this](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html).

Ok, here it is:

```
import java.io.*;

import org.eclipse.swt.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;

public class Gui
{
    protected Shell shlScrambledata;
    private CCombo  cmbDocType;
    private CCombo  cmbDocModel;
    private Text    txtFile2Read;
    private Text    txtScrambleFile;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Gui window = new Gui();
            window.open();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void open()
    {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        createContents();
        shlScrambledata.open();
        shlScrambledata.pack();
        while (!shlScrambledata.isDisposed())
        {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    }

    private void createContents()
    {
        shlScrambledata = new Shell();
        shlScrambledata.setText("ScrambleData");
        shlScrambledata.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

        // Create the document type group
        Group docTypeGroup = new Group(shlScrambledata, SWT.SHADOW_ETCHED_IN);
        docTypeGroup.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.BEGINNING, true, false, 2, 1));
        docTypeGroup.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
        docTypeGroup.setText("Choose a Document Type");

        cmbDocType = new CCombo(docTypeGroup, SWT.BORDER);
        cmbDocType.setItems(new String[] { "ACC710", "COMKB", "DEB442", "DEB443", "DEB444", "DEB814", "FAC617", "INC411", "INC715", "KLT334 ", "KLT355", "KLT358", "KLT361", "OVK710", "PKOA" });
        cmbDocType.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

        // Create the document model group
        Group docModelGroup = new Group(shlScrambledata, SWT.SHADOW_ETCHED_IN);
        docModelGroup.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.BEGINNING, true, false, 2, 1));
        docModelGroup.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
        docModelGroup.setText("Choose a document model.");

        cmbDocModel = new CCombo(docModelGroup, SWT.BORDER);
        cmbDocModel.setItems(new String[] { "XML", "FlatFile", "COMklantbeeld" });
        cmbDocModel.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

        // create the file chooser for the fake addresslist
        Group grpSelectTheFake = new Group(shlScrambledata, SWT.SHADOW_ETCHED_IN);
        grpSelectTheFake.setText("Select the fake address list.");
        grpSelectTheFake.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.BEGINNING, true, false, 2, 1));
        grpSelectTheFake.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

        txtFile2Read = new Text(grpSelectTheFake, SWT.BORDER);
        txtFile2Read.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

        Button btnFileChooser = new Button(grpSelectTheFake, SWT.PUSH);
        btnFileChooser.setText("Browse");
        btnFileChooser.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter()
        {
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e)
            {
                FileDialog dialog = new FileDialog(shlScrambledata, SWT.NULL);
                String path = dialog.open();

                if (path != null)
                {
                    File file = new File(path);
                    txtFile2Read.setText(file.getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }
        });

        // create the filechooser for the file to be scrambled
        Group grpSelectScrambleFile = new Group(shlScrambledata, SWT.SHADOW_ETCHED_IN);
        grpSelectScrambleFile.setText("Select the file that you want to scramble.");
        grpSelectScrambleFile.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.BEGINNING, true, false, 2, 1));
        grpSelectScrambleFile.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

        txtScrambleFile = new Text(grpSelectScrambleFile, SWT.BORDER);
        txtScrambleFile.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

        Button btnSelectScrambleFile = new Button(grpSelectScrambleFile, SWT.NONE);
        btnSelectScrambleFile.setText("Browse");

        btnSelectScrambleFile.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter()
        {
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e)
            {
                FileDialog dialog = new FileDialog(shlScrambledata, SWT.NULL);
                String path = dialog.open();

                if (path != null)
                {
                    File file = new File(path);
                    txtScrambleFile.setText(file.getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }
        });

        // Create the scramble button
        Button btnScramble = new Button(shlScrambledata, SWT.NONE);
        shlScrambledata.setDefaultButton(btnScramble);
        btnScramble.setText("Scramble!");
        btnScramble.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter()
        {
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("DocType: " + cmbDocType.getText());
                System.out.println("DocModel: " + cmbDocModel.getText());
                System.out.println("AddressFile: " + txtFile2Read.getText());
                System.out.println("File2Scramble: " + txtScrambleFile.getText());

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

and will print the selected items when you click the button.

Comment: Hi Baz, Thanks for your quick reply. However, i'm can't get it compiled in Eclipse. The .setLayout is giving me the following error:
Multiple markers at this line
 - The method setLayout(Layout) in the type Composite is not applicable for the arguments 
  (GridLayout)

Comment: @Mijno You probably imported the wrong `GridLayout`. It should be `org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout`. You probably imported `java.awt.GridLayout`.

Comment: Oh, figured it out... didn't see the library's (sorry). This works fine! I was thinking way to complex obviously. Easy does it!

Comment: @Mijno Glad it worked out for you. Yeah, sometimes you don't realize that things could be done easier until someone points it out. Happens all the time.